# PHP if first var is empty use second one

Tags: php, if-statement, var

I have a little question if it is possible to check with a variable if one of two variables are not empty and to use their value? Like this:

```
$var1 = "";
$var2 = "123";
$varifnotempy= $var1 || $var2;
    
echo $varifnotempy;
```

Here I want not **2** because it give me which one is not empty, but I want that it returns me **123** and if `$var1` is not null then to use the value of `$var1`

I know that I can use if else, but I want to know if it possible to make it by variable.

Comment: quite a few ways to do this really, not just the one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The traditional way is with the condition (aka "ternary") operator:

```
$varifnotempty = $var1 ? $var1 : $var2;
```

Since 5.3 there's a shorthand:

```
$varifnotempty = $var1 ?: $var2;
```

Comment: thx for your answer it was realy helpful, can you please tell me how can i use "and not equal" in this context? For example i have one variable more $var3="5" and i want to verify if $var1 is not empy and not equal with $var3?

Comment: `(!empty($var1) && $var1 != $var3)`

Comment: he just return me 1 and say that $var1 is not empy but i need that if $var1 is for example 2 and is not eqal with 5 than turn me 2

Comment: So what's the problem? Use what I wrote in a normal ternary operator.

Comment: `(!empty($var1) && $var1 != 5) ? 2 : $var1`

Comment: $var1 = "";
$var2 = "123";
$var3="232";
if $var1 is not empy and not eqal with $var3 then use $var2

thats that i need.

Comment: This seems to be a completely different question from your original question. The standard conditional operator should handle it fine, what's confusing you?

Comment: `(!empty($var1) && $var1 != $var3) ? $var2 : $var1`

Comment: yes i know i have $var1 actually as different numbers and $var3 also, so i need when $var1 and $var3 are note equal then use $var1. Because somethime $var1 is not empty and it have the same value as $var3.

Comment: If all this is confusing you, just use a plain `if` statement. There's no need to write confusing code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) and the [ternary operator](https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators) like this:

```
<?php

$var1 = ''; 
$var2 = '123';

$varifnotempy = (!empty($var1)) ? $var1 : $var2; // => '123' because $var1 is an empty string

echo $varifnotempy;
```

`empty()` will return false if the var exists and has a non-empty value. Empty values are considered to be:

- "" (an empty string)
- 0 (0 as an integer)
- 0.0 (0 as a float)
- "0" (0 as a string)
- NULL
- FALSE
- array() (an empty array)

The ternary operator works like this: `$value = (if this is true) ? then set $value to this : otherwise set $value to this`. In other words `(condition) ? if true : if not true`

Comment: thx for your explication it was realy helpful, can you please how can i use "and not equal" in this context? For example i have one variable more  **$var3="5"** and i want to verify if **$var1** is not empy and not equal with **$var3**?

Comment: That would look something like: `$varifnotempty_andnotequaltovar3 = (!empty($var1) && $var1 !== $var3) ? $var1 : $var2;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like below:

```
$var1="";
$var2="123";

//one line condition code
$varifnotempy= $var1 ? $var1 : $var2;

//or
$varifnotempy= (!is_null($var1) && $var1!="") ? $var1 : $var2;

//or
$varifnotempy= (!isset($var1) || $var1!="") ? $var1 : $var2;

echo $varifnotempy;
```

Comment: It works even if $var1 is false or zero. Of course it will not work id false or zero is a string.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is perfect, but if you want clearer function calls you can use it like below:

```
$var1 = "";
$var2 = "abc";

$varNotEmpty = (empty($var1) === true) ? $var2 : $var1;
echo $varNotEmpty;
```

AKA.

```
$var1 = "";
$var2 = "abc";

if (empty($var1)) {
  $varNotEmpty = $var2;
} 
else {
  $varNotEmpty = $var1;
}

echo $varNotEmpty;
```

Comment: empty() returns a boolean value. No reason to do `(empty($var1) === true)` just do `empty($var1)`

Comment: Thanks, @Aknosis, but I was attempting to make a clear depiction. I always add the `=== true` just to make it easier for the reader when writing code. :)